# Boolean value return from Neo4j cypher query without CASE

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I know that you can do this

```
match (user:User {username:'${username}', password:'${password}'})
            RETURN
            CASE WHEN user.blocked='true' THEN true ELSE false END as blocked,
            user.username as username,
            user.uid as uid
```

But I hope to find a shorter way to return booleans with cypher, I am using nodejs and having CASE like this on every boolean props my objects have  seems very verbose... Is there a better way ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
CASE WHEN user.blocked='true' THEN true ELSE false END AS blocked
```

with this:

```
user.blocked='true' AS blocked
```

Now, if you actually stored a boolean value in the `blocked` property (instead of a string), the above can be simplified even further:

```
user.blocked AS blocked
```

*Aside: To further improve performance, you should probably use [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#cypher-parameters) instead of '${username}' and '${password}'.*

Comment: It was my mistake,  I was passing a string and not the boolean to start with. `match (user:User {uid:'${uid}'}) set user.blocked='${blocked}' return user.uid as uid, user.blocked as blocked` Thank you